# GMaps api Geocode strange behavior

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

I'm using gmaps apiv3 webservice to geocode with latlng couple. It's pretty simple but I have a strange behavior for some data.

Eq:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&region=fr&latlng=46.16141,-1.149797

Next I open url with a navigator (firefox / chrome) and at line `formatted_address` the value is :

```
<formatted_address>57-79 Rue des Merciers, 17000 La Rochelle, France</formatted_address>
```

But when I get xml file through PHP

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($xml)
```

result :

```
public 'formatted_address' => string '57-79 Rue des Merciers, 17000 Rochelle, France' (length=46)
```

the word 'La' before 'Rochelle' just disapear ... That my problem. And it's not a unique case (I can post more example).

I try also try with `file_get_contents, curl, wget` ... Same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the formatted street address is locale-aware and reacts to your browser's `accept-language` header, which probably is `fr-FR`.

If you would encode a position in London, you would get `Londres` in a french-language browser, `London` in an english one, `Lontoo` in a finnish one etc.

Use the [`language` parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) to force the language.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&
region=fr&latlng=46.16141,-1.149797&language=fr
```

Comment: I have tried with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr-FR; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1'); but not enough. Im going to find about accept-language on header.

Comment: @Kakawait check out my update, I found the parameter that overrides it. It's named `language`

Comment: Yeah thx I with language option it's works fine :') Was stupid problem hihi